# Streamreader locks file

Tags: c#, file, locking, streamreader

I have a c# app (Windows Service) that fires a timer event that reads files in a directory and sends out SMS using the data in the files. Next time the event fires, it tries to move the processed files in the "Processed" directory to a "Completed" directory before processing the new files. I keep getting a "File in use by another process" exception, although I am pretty sure that I dispose of everything that uses the files. If I stop the service and start it again, the files is released. Any ideas?

```
//Code that fires the timer    
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;

namespace SmsWindowsService
{
    public partial class SmsWindowsService : ServiceBase
    {
        private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

        public SmsWindowsService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("MatterCentreSMSSource"))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                    "MatterCentreSMSSource", "MatterCentreSMSLog");
            }
            elMatterCentreSMS.Source = "MatterCentreSMSSource";
            elMatterCentreSMS.Log = "MatterCentreSMSLog";

        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            string logText = string.Empty;

            logText = "MatterCentreSMS Service started successfully on " + DateTime.Now;

            WriteEventLog(logText);

            //Create a timer with a ten second interval.
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

            //Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

            //Set the Interval to 5 minutes.
            //aTimer.Interval = 300000;
            aTimer.Interval = 60000;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;

            // If the timer is declared in a long-running method, use
            // KeepAlive to prevent garbage collection from occurring
            // before the method ends.
            //GC.KeepAlive(aTimer);
            GC.Collect();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            string logText = string.Empty;

            logText = "MatterCentreSMS Service stopped on " + DateTime.Now;

            WriteEventLog(logText);
        }

        private void WriteEventLog(string logText)
        {
            elMatterCentreSMS.WriteEntry(logText);
        }

        private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            string ex = string.Empty;

            SendSms s = new SendSms();

            ex = s.ProcessSms();

            if (ex.Length > 1)
                WriteEventLog(ex);

            //ex = RestartService("SmsWindowsService", 60000);
            //WriteEventLog(ex);
        }

        public string RestartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
        {
            ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);

            try
            {
                int millisec1 = Environment.TickCount;
                TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

                service.Stop();
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);

                // count the rest of the timeout
                int millisec2 = Environment.TickCount;
                timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds - (millisec2 - millisec1));

                service.Start();
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);

                return "MatterCentreSMS Service successfully restarted on " + DateTime.Now;
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Convert.ToString(e);
            }
        }
    }
}

//Code that reads the file
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace SmsWindowsService
{
    class Message
    {
        private string filePath;

        public Message(string filePath)
        {
            this.filePath = filePath;
        }

        public string readSMS(string filePath)
        {
            const string searchmessage = "[B-->]";
            StreamReader smsmessage = new StreamReader(filePath);

            try
            {
                FileInfo filenameinfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
                if (filenameinfo.Exists == false)
                    throw new SMSReaderException(String.Format("SMS Message {0} cannot be found ...", filePath), filePath);

                smsmessage = filenameinfo.OpenText();
                string smsoutput = smsmessage.ReadToEnd();
                int endpos = smsoutput.IndexOf(searchmessage);
                smsoutput = smsoutput.Substring(endpos + searchmessage.Length);
                smsoutput = smsoutput.Replace("&", "&amp;");
                smsoutput = smsoutput.Replace("\"", "&quot;");
                smsoutput = smsoutput.Replace("'", "&#39;");

                filenameinfo = null;
                smsmessage.Close();
                smsmessage.Dispose();

                return smsoutput;
            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception("Help", e.InnerException);
            }

            finally
            {
                smsmessage.Close();
                smsmessage.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    public class SMSReaderException : System.IO.FileNotFoundException
    {
        public SMSReaderException(string message, string filename)
            : base(message, filename)
        {
        }
    }
    }

//Code that connects to web service and send sms
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Configuration;
using SmsWindowsService.EsendexSendSmsService;

namespace SmsWindowsService
{
    class SendSms
    {
        string filePath = string.Empty;
        string directoryPath = string.Empty;
        string directoryPathProcessing = string.Empty;
        string directoryPathCompleted = string.Empty;
        string smsLogfileDirectory = string.Empty;
        string smsLogfilePath = string.Empty;
        string mattercentreSMS = string.Empty;
        string messageBody = string.Empty;
        string messageId = string.Empty;
        string messageStatus = string.Empty;
        string dateTodayString = string.Empty;
        long mobileNumber;
        EsendexSendSmsService.SendService send;

        public SendSms()
        {
            directoryPath = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[@"directoryPath"];
            directoryPathProcessing = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[@"directoryPathProcessing"];
            directoryPathCompleted = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[@"directoryPathCompleted"];
            smsLogfileDirectory = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[@"smsLogfileDirectory"];            
            dateTodayString = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
            smsLogfilePath = smsLogfileDirectory + dateTodayString.Replace(@"/", "_") + ".txt";
            send = new EsendexSendSmsService.SendService();
        }

        public string ProcessSms()
        {
            string ex = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPathProcessing);

                ex = MoveFilesToCompleted(directoryPathProcessing, directoryPathCompleted);

                if (ex.Length > 1)
                    return ex;

                ex = MoveFilesToProcessing(directoryPath, directoryPathProcessing);

                if (ex.Length > 1)
                    return ex;

                FileInfo[] subFilesProcessing = di.GetFiles();

                foreach (FileInfo subFile in subFilesProcessing)
                {
                    filePath = directoryPathProcessing + subFile.Name;

                    Message sms = new Message(filePath);

                    mattercentreSMS = sms.readSMS(filePath);

                    MessageDetails d = new MessageDetails(mattercentreSMS);

                    mobileNumber = d.GetMobileNumber();
                    messageBody = d.GetMessageBody();

                    ex = SetHeader();

                    if (ex.Length > 1)
                        return ex;

                    ex = SetProxy();

                    if (ex.Length > 1)
                        return ex;

                    //Send the message and get the returned messageID and send status
                    messageId = send.SendMessage(Convert.ToString(mobileNumber), messageBody, EsendexSendSmsService.MessageType.Text);
                    messageStatus = Convert.ToString(send.GetMessageStatus(messageId));

                    ex = WriteLogFile(messageId, subFile.Name, messageStatus);

                    if (ex.Length > 1)
                        return ex;

                    send.Dispose();
                }

                di = null;
                subFilesProcessing = null;

                return ex;
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Convert.ToString(e);
            }
        }

        private string MoveFilesToCompleted(string directoryPathProcessing, string directoryPathCompleted)
        {
            DirectoryInfo din = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPathProcessing);

            try
            {                
                FileInfo[] subFiles = din.GetFiles();

                foreach (FileInfo subFile in subFiles)
                {
                    subFile.MoveTo(directoryPathCompleted + subFile.Name);
                }

                subFiles = null;
                return "";                
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Convert.ToString(e);
            }

            finally
            {
                din = null;
            }
        }

        private string MoveFilesToProcessing(string directoryPath, string directoryPathProcessing)
        {
            DirectoryInfo din = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);

            try
            {
                FileInfo[] subFiles = din.GetFiles();

                foreach (FileInfo subFile in subFiles)
                {
                    subFile.MoveTo(directoryPathProcessing + subFile.Name);
                }

                subFiles = null;
                return "";
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Convert.ToString(e);
            }

            finally
            {
                din = null;
            }
        }

        private string SetHeader()
        {
            try
            {
                //Setup account details in the header
                EsendexSendSmsService.MessengerHeader header = new EsendexSendSmsService.MessengerHeader();
                header.Account = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[@"smsServiceUrl"];
                header.Username = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[@"smsServiceUsername"];
                header.Password = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[@"smsServicePassword"];

                // set the SOAP header Authentication values
                send.MessengerHeaderValue = header;

                return "";
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Convert.ToString(e);
            }
        }

        private string SetProxy()
        {
            try
            {
                //Create a web proxy object as the proxy server block direct request to esendex 
                WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[@"proxyaddress"], true);
                myProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[@"username"], ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[@"password"]);
                WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = myProxy;
                send.Proxy = myProxy;

                return "";
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Convert.ToString(e);
            }
        }

        private string WriteLogFile(string messageId, string smsFileName, string messageStatus)
        {
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(smsLogfilePath))
                {
                    //file is not empty - append log entry to file
                    using (StreamWriter writeSmsLog = File.AppendText(smsLogfilePath))
                    {
                        writeSmsLog.WriteLine(messageId + "             " + smsFileName + "    " + DateTime.Now + "     " + messageStatus);
                        writeSmsLog.Close();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(smsLogfilePath);
                    fs.Flush();
                    fs.Close();
                    fs.Dispose();

                    using (StreamWriter writeSmsLog = new StreamWriter(smsLogfilePath, true))
                    {
                        writeSmsLog.WriteLine("Message_ID                                       File_Name                                    Date_Sent                  Status");
                        writeSmsLog.WriteLine("======================================================================================================================================");
                        writeSmsLog.WriteLine(messageId + "             " + smsFileName + "    " + DateTime.Now + "     " + messageStatus);
                        writeSmsLog.Close();
                    }
                }

                return "";
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Convert.ToString(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 did you really have to post all that code?

Comment: Please limit code posted in questions to relevant portions or samples that exemplify your problem.

Comment: I rather add more code than necessary and make sure that everybody have a clear understanding of what I am trying to achieve than frustrating people with vague questions.

Comment: A couple of suggestions: read up on `using` blocks http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.100).aspx , exception handling best practices http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET , and why calling `GC.Collect` is usually a bad idea http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/11/29/271829.aspx

Comment: Yeah, `using` blocks would be great.

Comment: @marius: If you had made more effort, you could have determined that at least some of the code is irrelevant.  Delete parts of the code and see if the problem still exists.  If it does, that code is irrelevant.  Don't rely on us to debug your code.  It's a lot more work for us than for you and it's work that you should be doing yourself regardless.

Comment: @Porges:I had everything in blocks, but found some suggestions that using blocks is out of date and thus changed it to see if it would make a difference. Also used GC.Collect to see if it would collect something that I might have missed to dispose of - desperate times calls for desperate measures.

Comment: @Brian:I surely did not ask you to debug my code - I want to know if other people have had the same experience and if they have any suggestions on the topic. The reason I added the code is to demonstrate that I do dispose of the relevant objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StreamReader smsmessage = new StreamReader(filePath);

try
{
    FileInfo filenameinfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
    ....
    smsmessage = filenameinfo.OpenText();
    ...
```

You are initializing smsmessage twice, but only disposing one of those instances.  The first line constructs a `StreamReader`, and then you overwrite your reference to that instance with the instance created by filenameinfo.OpenText().  That leaves you with an instance that no longer has any references and hasn't been disposed.  That instance might be holding a lock on the file and you have no guarantees on when it will be disposed.  Even if it isn't holding a lock, you should still fix this.

Answer (score 7):

> Any ideas?

You're running a virus checker in an entirely different process. It is detecting that the file has changed and is locking it momentarily in order to check it to see if the edit you just performed to the file introduced a virus. It'll unlock it in a couple of milliseconds.

Disabling your virus checker is a bad idea. Instead, you're just going to have to live with it; write your code to be robust in a world where there are lots of processes vying for locks on files.

Comment: :I also thought this might be an issue. As you can see the event only fires every 1 minute. I also tested it with the event firing only every 5 minutes, but this makes no difference. Thanks for the suggestion.